# Intel Inspector cannot find debug symbols Visual C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, debug-symbols, intel-inspector

I have just started to try out the Intel Inspector software for memory analysis in my Visual C++ MFC projects. The analysis run fine and some errors are found by the tool. However, I cannot naviage to the problem source files and code lines because Intel Inspector says that "Symbol information not found".

Further more it gives a recommendation: "Specify locations in a Project Properties dialog box search tab, then re-resolve the result".

I have naviagted to the Intel Inspector Project Properties dialog and added the Debug directory explicitly (when both the built .exe and .pdb files are created) and tried to re-analyze the application, but it makes no difference. What part am I missing, why does it not find any symbols?

I am running VS2010 (tried to run Intel Inspector both as a VS2010 plugin as well as the standalone version with same results), x64 Debug build configuration, Generate debug data set to "Yes" in Properties->Linker->Debugging.